# Google Play: what become ratings and comments when promoting from 'open testing' to 'production'?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I have an app in 'open testing' (= 'Early access'). I receive comments and ratings from my 'open testers'.

These comments and ratings are not visible on the store as I am in 'open testing'. Great.

Nevertheless, I work on improving my app until my ratings and comments are high enough.

My question is: once I am happy with my app and release it to production, will the ratings and comments of my 'test users' become visible on the store or will my comments and ratings start from 0 ?

Thanks !

Comment: The people are currently giving you what Google calls "Private Beta Feedback". This is not the same as a "Review" and therefore it will not be converted.